# Pass Id to ActionMethod

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Delete button inside my table and I m trying to delete the selected Row.

The problem is that I always get in the post method a null ID

```
<div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Role Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete","Role", new { id = item.Id },FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
                    </div>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

In My Controller

```
// POST: Jobs/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            IdentityRole role = _context.Roles.Find(id);
            _context.Roles.Remove(role);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Any time I click on the button the id is null

Comment: show us your routes?

Comment: `location.href` is a GET. You should not be attempting to make a GET call to a `Delete()` method. And your method is decorated with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` in anycase (but your not passing the token). Add a form and put a submit button inside it (and include `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I edited my code and I add the form but I still get a null ID

Comment: Your edited code should be fine. Are you sure `item.Id` has a value? - inspect the html your generating for the `<form>` tags

Comment: Here's what I get : <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" href="/Role/Delete/b1bc13ca-a855-48b0-90e2-9e5fc081ac86">Delete</a>

Comment: Man your genuis thank I forget about time Thank you

Comment: `b1bc13ca-a855-48b0-90e2-9e5fc081ac86` looks like a `Guid`, not an `int` - make it `Guid` or `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, the html generated in `<form>` tags is

```
action="/Role/Delete/b1bc13ca-a855-48b0-90e2-9e5fc081ac86"
```

meaning that the `Id` property of your model is typeof `Guid`. Change the POST method signature to

```
public ActionResult Delete(Guid id)
```